# Multiple super classes and code reuse

Tags: java, android, inheritance

This question is related to Android in that my need exists in that domain but the question still applies to Java as a whole; I will be using some Android terms here such as `Activity`, `FragmentActivity`, `ListActivity`, etc...

I need to implement an abstract base class that contains functionality which must be used throughout the whole application, more specifically every `Activity` must use this functionality but I want it to be handled automatically by the base class. My problem is that I have many different types of Activities within the application like `Activity`, `FragmentActivity` and `ListActivity`, all of which extend `Activity` (minus `Activity` of course).

Since the code in the base class would be exactly the same for each implementation of `Activity`, is there a way to avoid code duplication and needing to create a base class for each type of `Activity`?

What I'm trying to avoid:

```java
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle)
    {
        // code goes here, will be the exact same for all these base classes
    }
}

public abstract class BaseFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle)
    {
        // code goes here, will be the exact same for all these base classes
    }
}

public abstract class BaseListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle)
    {
        // code goes here, will be the exact same for all these base classes
    }
}

public class MyMainActivity extends BaseActivity
{
}

public class MyUserList extends BaseListActivity
{
}

public class SomeActivityThatNeedsToBeAFragment extends BaseFragmentActivity
{
}
```

I was trying to utilize generics for this by using something like the following

```java
public abstract class BaseActivity<T extends Activity> extends T
```

but obviously that won't work; or maybe I'm just doing it wrong. So is there any way to accomplish this code reuse and avoid duplication or am I just simply stuck duplicating my code?

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem, What I have done was, I had only one base activity which extends FragmentActivity, I used fragments whenever I need other functionalities, Still i can create list view inside FragmentActivity

Comment: Would it be possible to simply move the common code that would go in all those onCreate methods into a utility class, and have them call it?

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, this would be possible and similar to option 2 of `G. Blake Meike`'s answer but again even this has a degree of code duplication since I have to pretty much insert cookie cutter code into each and every Activity to utilize this utility class and this comes with its own set of problems like ensuring that a developer remembers to use this utility class in hopes that one or two activities don't slip through the cracks and present erratic behavior to the user.

Comment: A developer only has to remember to extends the appropriate base class, no? `public class ZooListActivity extends BaseListActivity`. Of course, even if Java had multiple inheritance, a developer would still have to remember to extend BaseListActivity instead of ListActivity, right?

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, but remembering to extend `BaseListActivity` is easier than (in my situation) remembering to hookup (so far) 5 methods to the utility class with every newly created Activity. Also, extending BaseListActivity still makes it so I have to have a base class for each type of activity which has code duplication, granted if I use a utility class inside the abstract base classes then there is less work but still quite a bit of duplication.

Comment: But in my example you would only have to remember to extend `BaseListActivity`, and it would have only one line of code duplication: a call to the utility class. The contents of onCreate() would be just that one call, and all the common code would live in one place: the utility class. I think we are talking at cross purposes.

Comment: @DavidConrad No, I understand what you mean, and in my example it is just one line in onCreate but in reality my code would need 1 line of code for (currently) 5 methods and I would need to duplicate BaseListActivity for each type of Activity that I need so basically I would have one base class that extends Activity, one that extends ListActivity, one that extends FragmentActivity and so on and so forth for each one I need... all of which would be almost exact copies of each other with lines calling methods inside the utility class.

Comment: @DavidConrad I can see how this would be useful for code management in terms of something needing to change; using this method I would only have to change the method inside the utility class and not 5 identical base classes, but if I add a method, then I need to go back and add the corresponding method to each of the base classes and once again copy code. I'm not saying your solution is wrong and in fact might be what I end up using but it's not addressing the issue at hand which is code duplication... What the issue is might not be solvable within the constraints of Java.

Comment: I agree, there might not be a better solution in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frequently, using Fragments can help with this kind of problem.  In your particular case, though I see that you want to use ListActivity, as well.  That makes it harder

As you know, Java can't help you here.  You can't inherit multiple implementations (List and MyBase).  There is no simple answer.  I can suggest two things:

- List(Activity,Fragment) are pretty simple extensions to their base classes.  You could, with a reasonable amount of work, build your own, that inherit from your base class.  They would probably be simpler than the ones in the framework.  Maybe that would be ok.
- Delegate.  Write a class that implements the common behavior but that does not inherit from Activity/Fragment.  Create one of these objects during the initialization of your Fragment/Activity classes.  Any time there is common behavior, delegate it to the delegate instance.

Comment: +1 for a good response. Unfortunately there is complex functionality that I do utilize inside the various activity classes so option 1 is out. Options 2 would work but I'm trying to avoid having to instantiate and keep a reference to this custom class and "hook" everything up in each activity I end up creating; which is why I wanted a base class with the required functionality and extend from that so it's just "magically" taken care of. Looks like a might end up just having to deal with code duplication anyways; option 2 also has some code duplication in it as well with the delegations.

Comment: Ya, I know what you mean about having to write the delegation code again and again.  Feh!  So, what about a synthesis: Go ahead and write the 4 super classes -- vanilla and list based versions of Activity/Fragment -- and have *them* do the delegation to the implementation of the complex functionality.  You know you gotta do it... ;-)

Comment: @g-blake-meike I'm afraid that is what I'm going to end up doing `DavidConrad` and I were discussing that exact thing in the comments of the question. I am going to accept your answer since the 2nd option you provided is what will be used, with the exception that the delegation will occur in the super classes like you've said above.

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract class called `BaseActivity`.  Implement `onCreate()` for it, which should cover the basics of activity operations.  Create other classes that extend from `BaseActivity`, and allow them to override that method if and only if they do something slightly more special than `BaseActivity`.

The main idea here is that whatever `Activity` you have or create relates to one another in some way that they do similar code operations.  Only in special cases would you need to do something extra, hence overriding `onCreate()`.

Comment: I do need to do something special in onCreate which is why I'm creating a class that extends `Activity` to override that method but in Android you need to have your "displayable" classes extend a form of Activity but there are other things that already extend Activity. For example: FragmentActivity extends Activity and provides its own special functionality and I need this functionality but I also need my functionality in the base class so if the base class extends Activity it will be missing all the FragmentActivity functionality.